# Probability generating function and a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, functions, generating-functions

A discrete random variable $X$ has probability generating function $G_X(t)$. If $Y=aX+b$ show that the probability generating function of $Y$ is given by $G_X(t)=t^bG_X(t^a)$. Hence prove that $E(Y)=aE(X)+b$ and that Var$(Y)=a^2$Var$(X)$.

I'm currently learning probability generating functions and I am confused with this question. I've attempted to express $G_Y(t)$ using its definition, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm not even sure I know how to approach this question. I appreciate any help- thank you!

Comment: Which part is currently confusing you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @daOnlyBG I attempted to write $G_Y(t)$ in using its definition but I can't go further. In fact, I don't know how to approach this question

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$G_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[t^X].$$  Thus $$G_Y(t) = \operatorname{E}[t^{aX+b}] = \operatorname{E}[(t^a)^X t^b] = t^b \operatorname{E}[(t^a)^X] = t^b G_X(t^a),$$ as claimed, because $t$ and $b$ are constants with respect to the expected value.  For the second part, how is the probability generating function related to the moments of a random variable?

Comment: @Cherryblossoms Your own answer arrives at the same result as what I wrote.  My definition of $G_X(t)$ is the same as yours (except you unnecessarily restrict $X$ to be discrete).  Nowhere in my answer do I even use the phrase "moment generating function."  So I am completely perplexed as to why you claim I am talking about a moment generating function.  A MGF is **not** the same as moments of a random variable.

Comment: Totally agreed. My comment about MGF is incorrect. I am taking it down. (It probably arose as PGF is always defined for integer-valued RVs, my humble apologies for that).

Answer (score 0):

(Stumbled upon this question by chance. Apologies for bringing up this again.)
We define the probability generating function of $X$ as $G_X(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)t^k$. 
The probability generating function of $Y$ is $G_Y(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(Y=k)t^k. $ Since $Y=\alpha X+\beta, Y\in \{\beta, \alpha+\beta,\ldots\}. $ Then
$$\begin{align}
G_Y(t) & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(Y=k)t^k =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(Y=\alpha n +\beta)t^{\alpha n +\beta}\\
& =\sum_{n =0}^{\infty}P(X=n)t^{\alpha n +\beta} = \sum_{n =0}^{\infty}t^{\beta} P(X=n)t^{\alpha n} = t^{\beta}G_X(t^{\alpha}).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your definition for $G$ is inadequate:  what if $X$ does not have discrete support?  The original question does not require $X$ to be a discrete random variable.